# Command run `aws configure` does not recognize `aws_secret_access_key`

Tags: amazon-ecr

I created an IAM access key. It comes with an access key and a secret access key. After filling the fields below with respective strings `account_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`, I run the command `aws ecr get-login-password --region sa-east-1`.

```
AWS Access Key ID [None]: account_id
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: aws_secret_access_key
Default region name [None]: sa-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

The commmand output is below. Can anybody help solve this simple issue?

`An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`